# Swift, воспроизведение mp3 в фоне

Tags: ios, swift

У меня с периодичностью запускается фоновый поток `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()`, который проверяет наличие в базе записей с определенным статусом

Если такие записи есть, то необходимо воспроизвести mp3.

Делал воспроизведение с помощью:

**1. AVAudioPlayer**

Включил `Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture в BackgroundModes`

```
    do {
    try   AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    return print("error")
    }
```

Установил категорию `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`

Проблема: на открытом экране каждые 20 секунд издается звук (играет музыка), а вот когда просто сверну приложение, звук сам уже не воспроизводится.

**2. AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1009)**

Работал но APPLE отклоняли с причиной "Включен режим `backgroundModes` но ни чего не воспроизводится".

Что можно использовать для такой задачи?

**UPD**

Это метод который запускает таймер с интервалом 20 секунд:

```
func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: #selector(ListOfOrders.checkNewOrder), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
registerBackgroundTask()
}
```

Это метод, который запускает таймер, в котором происходит закачка и проверка данных. Если есть новые данные, в теории телефон должен пищать

```
func checkNewOrder() {
WorkWithInternet().getOrders(self, token: prefs.stringForKey("token")!, col: 0, add: false, vc: ListOfOrders())
}
```

**UPD2** Воспроизведение звука по файлу:

```
do {
    let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("notif", withExtension: "mp3")!
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
    audioPlayer!.delegate = self
    audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer!.play()
}catch{
    print("Error")
}
```

**UPD3**

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

Регистрирует таск в фоне:

```
func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
    [unowned self] in
    self.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
 }
```

Функция завершения бэкграунд-таска:

```
func endBackgroundTask() {
   NSLog("Background task ended.")
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
   backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

Comment: Аналогичные вопросы на [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882737/how-to-play-background-music-with-swift-2-0) не помогают?

Comment: да вполне достаточно искать по таким же словам, что и у вас в заголовке) я нашел [так.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=swift+play+music+in+background)

Comment: @Denis, не помогло. Это не то, что нужно, у меня в проекте есть этот код тоже. Тот блок кода нужен, чтоб продолжить воспроизведение звука в фоне, если вышел из активити приложения, а мне нужно, чтоб звук мог  начать воспроизводиться, когда приложение уже свёрнуто, например, через 20 секунд. Кстати, по Вашему 2-му комментарию. Естественно) На enSO так же задал этот вопрос. И там тоже, тишина

Comment: покажите код, как вы запускаете каждые 20 секунд

Comment: сделайте плейлист чтоб через один шли пустые треки длинной 20 секунд, или опять же сделайте плейлист чтобы каждый трек был 20 секунд тишины и потом ваш звук в конце

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил код, который вы просили в **UPD**

Comment: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval точно работать не будет. Когда приложение на бэкграунде и воспроизведение текущего трека закончилось у вас есть примерно 5 секунд, чтобы начать воспроизводить новый.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вообще, у меня так работает: приложение в фоне проверяет данные с сервера каждые 20 секунд. Если есть новые данные, надо как-то вывести звуковое уведомление. Нотификацию, как я знаю, невозможно создать в фоне. Можно, пока приложение открыто, создать отложенную нотификацию, чтоб воспроизвелось в фоне. А есть вообще метод, который запускает хоть какой-то звук именно в фоне?

Comment: если у вас каждые 20 секунд приложение тянет что то с сервера, значит оно активно в этот момент. значит и музыку должно играть. Может у вас ничего с сервера и не тянется

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Все тянется, все работает (в логах все приходит), но не удается сделать именно старт музыки в фоне. mp3 файл находится в самом приложении и обращаюсь к нему вот так **UPD2** в вопросе

Comment: а как вы создаете таск, который будет работать на бэкграунде?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил в **UPD3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взгляни на [этот проект из книги](https://github.com/vandadnp/iOS-8-Swift-Programming-Cookbook/tree/master/chapter-concurrency/Playing%20Audio%20in%20the%20Background/Playing%20Audio%20in%20the%20Background)

Я лично протестировал его на iOS 9.3 iPhone 6+ все работает.